# I'm trying to understand this c# code how would it work in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand this c# code:

```
sum += (myName[i]) * Math.Pow(i+5,i+1);
```

how would this work in python?

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: Math.Pow(i+5,i+1) was the bit i didn't understand,

Answer (score 0):

As long as the types are correct, the python syntax would be:

```
sum += (myName[i]) * ((i + 5) ** (i + 1))
```

The ** is the exponentiation operator in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `math` module:

```
import math   # This will import math module

sum = 0
myName = [1,2,3,4,5]

i = 3 # array index
sum += (myName[i]) * math.pow(i+5,i+1)

print sum
```

### Working fiddle: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_xxRNH8VUra_0.py